# Multithreaded removal of HttpRuntime.Cache items upon expiration

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, caching, iis-7.5, httpruntime.cache

Even if I use lock with static locker object to lock my code from accessing the same item at the same time, how can I guarantee that this item is not removed by HttpRuntime from another thread during my lock ? I don't see any SyncRoot property in HttpRuntime or HttpRuntime.Cache.

If I specify expiration callback and lock my static locker object inside that callback, would it be proper to do that ?

Is it bad to lock HttpRuntime.Cache expiration thread inside callback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for a "SyncRoot" property suggests that you use the `SyncRoot` property when using locking in combination with a collection. There's a reason why, although it is supported by later collections for backwards-compatibility, it tends to be hidden through implementing the interface explicitly. Really, the `SyncRoot`  idea wasn't a very good one.

In this case, you're talking about a thread-safe collection, so there's even less need. `System.Web.Caching.Cache` does its own locking (or other mechanisms, it's specified to be threadsafe rather than to be threadsafe through a particular approach), so adding, accessing and removing an item from the collection across several threads won't corrupt it.

The only remaining risk, is if either the object itself isn't threadsafe, or if you access it from the collection several times in the same thread.

The second is easily avoided by not doing so. If you do:

```
(HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(someKey) as SomeType).SomeMethod();
(HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(someKey) as SomeType).SomeOtherMethod();
```

This only makes sense if you *want* to possibly be dealing with a different object in the second call than the first. Otherwise, it's easily resolved:

```
SomeType obj = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(someKey) as SomeType;
obj.SomeMethod();
obj.SomeOtherMethod();
```

(You also get a slight performance improvement by not calling the `Get` method repeatedly.

If you need to worry about different threads calling `SomeMethod()` and `SomeOtherMethod()` at the same time you need to either ensure that those methods are threadsafe, or lock on an object that relates to the object in question. Most of the time the most obvious choice for an object that relates to an object, is that object itself. Hence:

```
SomeType obj = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(someKey) as SomeType;
lock(obj)
{
  obj.SomeMethod();
  obj.SomeOtherMethod();
}
```

(Note that even if `SomeMethod()` and `SomeOtherMethod()` were threadsafe, we might still need to do this if the combination of them wasn't thread-safe. E.g. if the first reported on the objects state and we decided on the basis of that whether or not to perform the second, then we'd normally need to lock around that to prevent the state changing between the first and the second method call).

Of course, all other operations on the object would need to be locked in the same manner. It gets more complicated if we've multiple objects we need to synchronise as a unit. Then we need a more complicated rule about what object we lock on that simply locking on the object in question; because there's no single "object in question".

Comment: Interesting observation - I also never had to use SyncRoot on collections. And the reason is that I don't expect anything other than my code to modify those collections so I use my own object or collection object to lock when needed. In this case framework updates it whenever it wants, potentially at the same time as I am handling requests - hence my concern.

Comment: @alpav the idea was that different code - both internal and external to the collection - could agree on how to lock it. Unfortunately, without a mechanism on how to fit that into any wider locking (e.g. locking on two different collections at the same time), it doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

The cache is a private cache for your application.  The only time the runtime does anything to it is when the application is restarted (i.e. it clears the cache).  When you add an item to the cache, you can provide a callback to be informed of removals if you really want to be sure nothing else is messing with your cache.

I think it would be better to design the application and what is in the cache in such a ways as to minimize the need for two things to be accessing the same item in the cache though.  Having a need for two threads to be accessing the same item in the cache suggests there's a design issue.

Comment: The purpose of my cache is to save data to be reused for different queries (coming from multiple threads) that have same signatures, which consequently means that different threads will potentially try to access and create if not exists same cache item. What is wrong with my purpose(design) ?